# How to make all the size of the card component in Daisy UI vertically equal to the one beside it

Tags: tailwind-css, astrojs, daisyui

I am using the daisy UI with astro static site generator for creating a blog, the card component of daisy UI is used and the problem is cards adjacent to each other get different size based on the content length in each card, is there a way I can stretch adjacent card with lesser content grow to the height of the largest content card in the same row so that the UI looks consistent and of same size. [image]

Below is the card component code I am using.

```
 <article class="m-2">
        <div class="card card-bordered w-96 bg-base-100 border-yellow-600">
          <figure><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/225/arch" alt={post.frontmatter.title.split(" ").splice(0,4).join(" ")}/></figure>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.frontmatter.description.split(" ").splice(0,4).join(" ")}</p>
            <div class="card-actions justify-end">
              <a href={post.url}><button class="btn btn-primary">Read More....</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
```

I would expect that the height of the adjacent card is same and the maximum height is decided by the largest content card in the row.

Comment: you have to set a div with `flex` class and inside, put your cards

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example - it doesn't include any of your styles from Daisy UI, but it shows the effect of using `display: flex` on the containing `article` element.

The shorter card will match the size of other cards in the same row.

```css
.m-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.m-2 .card {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<article class="m-2">
  <div class="card card-bordered w-96 bg-base-100 border-yellow-600">
    <figure><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/225/arch" alt={post.frontmatter.title.split( " ").splice(0,4).join( " ")}/></figure>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1 class="card-title">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <p>A longer card.</p>
      <p>A longer card.</p>
      <p>A longer card.</p>
      <p>A longer card.</p>
      <div class="card-actions justify-end">
        <a href={post.url}><button class="btn btn-primary">Read More....</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-bordered w-96 bg-base-100 border-yellow-600">
    <figure><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/225/arch" alt={post.frontmatter.title.split( " ").splice(0,4).join( " ")}/></figure>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h1 class="card-title">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <p>A shorter card.</p>
      <div class="card-actions justify-end">
        <a href={post.url}><button class="btn btn-primary">Read More....</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```